# Reading a text file with parent directory and file name containing spaces

Tags: external-files, directory

I need to read the content of a text file located in a directory containing spaces. In addition, the filename might also contain spaces.

For example, reading the following text file:

**C:\My Documents\Some Directory\File 01.txt**

I can read files that don't contain spaces using this code:

```
\newread\file
\openin\file=c:/myfolder/test.txt
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \read\file to\fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline
    \fileline
\repeat
\closein\file
```

But as soon as I try to change the second line with one of these, it simply doesn't work:

```
\openin\file=c:/my folder/test.txt
\openin\file=c:/myfolder/test 01.txt
\openin\file=c:/My Documents/Some Directory/File 01.txt
```

Any ideas what I could do to include spaces?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The complete solution, as per the answer from David Carlisle:

```
\newread\file
\openin\file="C:/My Documents/Some Directory/File 01.txt"
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
    \read\file to\fileline 
    \fileline
\repeat
\closein\file
```

Comment: I am not sure. But try using a `back slash` as, `c:/my\ folder/test.txt` and `c:/myfolder/test\ 01.txt`.

Comment: It didn't work, "\openin\file" seems to thing that there's multiple arguments...

Comment: does putting the path in {} helps to prevent the misinterpretation as multiple arguments?

Comment: No, the following doesn't work either: \openin\file={c:/my folder/test.txt}

Comment: and a combination? `\openin\file={c:/my\ folder/test.txt}`? By the way, i would recommend to break the habit of giving names with spaces to files/folders. Use _ instead to get rid of exactly this problems. Every command line program and/or script will thank you.

Comment: @audiophiel you can not use `{}` around file names (apart from in luatex) and `\ ` won't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In web2c based implementations (nearly all currently used ones) you can use

```
\openin\file="a file with spaces"
```

(also use the same quoted syntax with `\input`)

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm I tried it before creating this post, but I may have made a typo somewhere... Thanks!